# How to display only the overwritten files while unzipping a .zip file?

Tags: windows, powershell

I am successfully able to extract contents of a file using:

```
Expand-Archive -Force -LiteralPath c:\folder\my_file.zip -DestinationPath c:\dest_folder
```

However, it is not displaying the files which are `overwritten`.

**How to display only the files which are overwritten?**

I am getting an error while running the command:

```
Expand-Archive -LiteralPath .\my_file.zip -DestinationPath .\Destination\ -Force -Verbose 4>&1 |
Select-String 'Remove File'
```

Error:

```
The ampersand (&) character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; wrap an ampersand in double 
quotation marks ("&") to pass it as part of a string.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingFileSpecification
```

Comment: Don't use `-Force` and capture the exceptions so you know which files "would have been" overwritten

Comment: without `-force`, I am not able to modify existing files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to replace the existing files but also know which ones where replaced, an alternative would be to [redirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7.2) the [verbose stream to the success stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_output_streams?view=powershell-7.2) and filter by those lines containing **"Remove File"**. `Expand-Archive` when using `-Verbose`, will output the following when replacing (removing first and then creating) a file:

> Performing the operation "Remove File" on target .....

In that sense, you can do the following:

```sh
Expand-Archive -LiteralPath .\my_file.zip -DestinationPath .\Destination\ -Force -Verbose 4>&1 |
Select-String 'Remove File'
```

Comment: thanks. can you help me understand what `4>&1` is doing?

Comment: @meallhour that's how you redirect _verbose_ (`4`) to _success_ (`1`). I added both links to my answer

Comment: one quick question. why we need to redirect verbose to success stream. why just not do this instead - `Expand-Archive -LiteralPath .\my_file.zip -DestinationPath .\Destination\ -Force -Verbose |
Select-String 'Remove File'`

Comment: @meallhour That's a good question, to put it simple, `Select-String` can't see / capture the verbose stream (or any other stream that is not the _success_ one)

Comment: @meallhour my pleasure, happy to help

Comment: I am getting an error `The ampersand (&) character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; wrap an ampersand in double 
quotation marks ("&") to pass it as part of a string.`

Comment: @meallhour can you update your question pasting literally the command you're running?

Comment: I have updated my question. getting an error while running `Expand-Archive -LiteralPath .\my_file.zip -DestinationPath .\Destination\ -Force -Verbose 4>&1 |
Select-String 'Remove File'`  How to escape `ampersand (&)`?

Comment: @meallhour The only way I could replicate this error is if there is a leading or trailing space: `4> &1` or `4>& 1` or `4> & 1`. In any of the cases, this is a typo, the redirection must be all together, no spaces are allowed.

Comment: It is fixed. it was failing due to space issue. thanks for the quick help!!

Comment: I am not getting any error but it is displaying the blank output:  `Performing extract on server





server1 E:\workspace>exit 0 `